# How to count occurrences main category wise for a month in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, countif

As shown in below image, need to count tick marks month wise and main category wise.
For example for April month there are total 7 ticks in main category and 7 tics in main category_1.
How to formulate it.

[image]

I want to count the tick mark for a month(Apr-23,Jun-23, Sep-23 ) by category(Main Category, Main Category_1) by formulation.

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS()` function.

Comment: I used the formula =COUNTIFS(A3:A6,"Apr-23",B3:F6,"P") but is giving error. P stands for tick mark

Comment: This should work for you : `=SUMPRODUCT((B3:F6="ü")*(TEXT(A3:A6,"mmm-yy")="Apr-23"))` change the `ü` to `P`, `Apr-23` is a date and not formatted as text, unless its a text formatted on your end, it solely depends . also please show where you need the expected output

Comment: Mayukh Bhattacharya It works thank you so much.!! But one more thing, if I wish to refer Apr-23 in formula =SUMPRODUCT((B3:F6="ü")*(TEXT(A3:A6,"mmm-yy")="Apr-23")) to a cell value then what correction to be made. Thank you in advance

Comment: Wait i will updated. Essentially when you formatted the dates as `mmm-yy` it assumes that the dates are the first day of the month, unless you have other manually did something else. `Apr-23` needs to be within speech marks i.e. `""` double quotes. See answer i have an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using <kbd>SUMPRODUCT()</kbd> or <kbd>SUM()</kbd> if using `MS365`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B9</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:F6="ü")*(TEXT(A3:A6,"mmm-yy")="Apr-23"))
```

---

**Notes:** Change `ü` to `P` and months are actually dates, so it needs to converted to text format, like shown in formula.

---

Look at this example below, i have used a cell reference to make it dynamic, here the cell <kbd>A9</kbd> is an actual date formatted as `mmm-yy` and used the following formula.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B9</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A9>=$A$3:$A$6)*($A$3:$A$6<=EOMONTH(A9,0))*(B3:F6="ü"))
```

---